# Can't see the database used by the default MVC Account Controller/ASP.NET Membership provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I fired up a new Internet application type MVC 3 project. It has an Account Controller that works using the default ASP.NET membership provider.

The web.config of the project has the following connection string:

```
connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I do have SQLEXPRESS on my machine, but when I look up the databases in the Management Studio, I do not see any database created for membership. I only see the ones that I created.

Where does ASP.NET MVC create this membership database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a User Instance (contained the file`aspnetdb.mdf` in your SQL installations' `data` directory) not an embedded database within SQLExpress, which is why you don't see it in SSMS.

Here's an [explanation of what this is](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2006/11/22/connecting-to-sql-express-user-instances-in-management-studio.aspx) and how to interrogate the data within it, should you need to.